# Run Task Manager In Xubuntu as Superuser

Tags: command-line, 14.04, sudo, xfce

I am trying to change the priority of a process in my system via Xubuntu's Task Manager by typing `sudo taskmgr`, but taskmgr isn't the name of the executable. What is the name of the executable program and if I change the priority of a process and restart my computer, will the process have the same priority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `sudo` to start graphical applications. ([More infos](https://askubuntu.com/a/11766/265974))

This should work:

```
sudo xfce4-taskmanager
```

Then go to settings on top left and then click on "Show all processes".

But the root xfce4-taskmanager shows only the root processes...
Perhaps this is a better solution to set your priorities:

[Change niceness (priority) of a running process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48708/change-niceness-priority-of-a-running-process)

The priority of a process will be lost if you close the process. But you can start any process with a certain priority: [Do all apps start with a normal priority on the system monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132355/do-all-apps-start-with-a-normal-priority-on-the-system-monitor)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd say *never*, [`sudo -i ...` is acceptable AFAIK](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6634/psa-gksu-is-no-longer-installed-by-default).